# Copy created primary key ID back to the temp table from which new row values are taken?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a temp table #temp

```
tid    tcol1     tcol2
--------------------
null   1        a
null   2        b
null   3        c
```

I am using #temp to insert values into table table1
`select tcol1, tcol2 into table1 from #temp`. Now the table1 looks like

```
id    col1     col2
---------------------
1      1        a
2      2        b
3      3        c
```

Now I want to copy the ID back to the #temp table. I am trying to get #temp table like

```
tid    tcol1     tcol2
--------------------
 1        1        a
 2        2        b
 3        3        c
```

Is this possible. If yes how?

Comment: I was trying to give in a table format, but that was all i was able give. Sorry for the mess.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - I recommend you use the edit function to edit your question and do the necessary formatting. Users on SO are quite helpful - but most of us would prefer to see a properly formatted question (and I think you'd agree)!

Comment: @onlyphantom thanks for the suggestion. i was able to format it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure in your real application, but here you can delete rows from #temp and insert from table1.

```
Delete from #temp

Insert into #temp 
Select id, tcol1, tcol2 from table1
```

But for sure a more sensible way would be not to copy the data back and forth. Generate id's before entering into #temp.

Comment: I should have thought this, thanks for the timely help.

Answer (score 0):

Drop #temp and then

```
SELECT * INTO #temp FROM table1
```